cognito wont load hosted ui login page, instead i get "An error was encountered with the requested page."
Does anyone know why i am getting this error "An error was encountered with the requested page."
i am developing application and i am using aws cognito as a authoraziation server, i am using insomnia, oauthdebugger and oauth2 client server to test cognito hosted ui, there seems to be a problem that keeps happening, after a while 4-7 times of me loging in, i cant see the login page again instead i see the image below "An error was encountered with the requested page." and the url looks like this.
"https://DOMAIN-REGION.amazoncognito.com/error?error=invalid_request&client_id=CLIENTID"
keep in mind i haven't made big changes, a moment ago everything was working and the login page was being loaded and after seccessfull login i was getting tokens
this is making me wonder if there is a rate limit
An error was encountered with the requested page.
i tested removing all session and cookies, i even installed another browser, and create another app client.
i would love to know why i am getting this error

I’ve fixed it. In application.properties, I added:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic

And then I created a new userpool and client app. Everything seems to work now just fine now.
